# The window.Print() function is not working in Microsoft edge when cancelled the first time

Tags: microsoft-edge

Version 91.0.864.41
Steps to reproduce:

1. call window.print();
2. on popup click cancel.
3. call window.print() again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some simple tests (Version 91.0.864.41) and found that it always works, I think this has to require more information. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Check This Out</title>
    <script>
        window.print();
        function CallPrint() {
            window.print();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="callPrint" onclick="CallPrint()">Print this page</button>
</body>
</html>
```

What does not work mean? Does it no longer show pop-up windows? Still failed to print? If you can provide a minimal example to reproduce the problem, it will be helpful to solve the problem, thank you for your understanding.

Comment: The popup no longer shows up again, and also the print() function becomes undefined.

Comment: Hi Singh Arpita, Did you rewrite the window.print() function?